# background-image phonegap jquery mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, background

I had a backround in my phonegap app, I update the image but now I can't see the image in my application.

It works fine if I open with the browser but not in the application.

A background-color works fine in the application

I try

```
.ui-page{
    background-image:url('../img/bg.jpg');
}
```

and

```
.ui-content{
    background-image:url('../img/bg.jpg');
}
```

This is maybe a path issue

I have:

```
assets/www/index.html
assets/www/css/style.css
assets/www/img/bg.jpg
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try   `background-image:url('img/bg.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

@ant try like this,it may help for you,

background:  url(../images/home-icon.png) no-repeat;

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem, it was due to a problem in the photoshop format, I don't know realy why